# Cocos2d node over uikit element

Tags: uikit, cocos2d-iphone

I've got a CCScene with few UIKit elements [UITextView for example].
After some user interaction I want to open a popup over the scene to also cover part of the UITextView.
It doesn't matter what z index I am using, it will always appear under the text view.
Any tips on how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CCNodes are drawn within the EAGLView Cocos is using. You need to manage the order of EAGLView(s) relative to other UIViews. Take a look at http://www.gdcvault.com/play/1012504/The-Best-of-Both-Worlds for an example of mixing Cocos drawing in EAGLViews with other UIKit views.

Comment: could you be more specific please? The document you are pointing to is not really helpful since it's a completely different scenario. Not really cocos2d.

Comment: Cocos2d can only display CCNodes within a EAGLView. It's exactly the same problem. However maybe you'll find http://www.raywenderlich.com/4817/how-to-integrate-cocos2d-and-uikit helpful.

The short answer is still that you need multiple EAGLViews. A single EAGLView cannot draw itself both above and below some other UIView.

Comment: U guess there's no way to do that 'easily' - that is using regular cocos2d flow. Anyway... I ended up hiding the elements before showing the popup. Not really an ideal way, but it will suffice for now. Thanks.

Comment: You can introduce a dummy UIView to which you add the EAGLView as well as your UIKit views. In that way you can order the various views according to what you need, so you can have UIKit views in the background AND in the foreground. See the Cocos2D-With-UIKit example in Kobold2D to see how it's done: http://www.kobold2d.com

Answer (score 0):

Another thought, and I'm saying this off the top of my head without trying first...

From memory, you can, from a UIView get an image of that views contents.  If, after the user interaction is done and you want to place your popup over the text field, you could create an UIimage from it, turn that into a texture, create a ccsprite from that and place it in the sam e spot on the screen.  You could then hide the actual text field and then pop up your popup.  The user wouldn't be able to tell the difference.

Comment: but then I would have to through positioning hell when detecting clicks on buttons on the popup ;) I've got around 5 types of popups, including ones with text fields, +/- buttons and normal buttons.

Comment: Sorry but I understood from your question that the popup was to be shown __after__ the user interaction, so I figured that a fake would not get in the way.