# cocos2d with uikit table layer order

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

Im following the excellent tutorial [Integrate cocos2d and UIKit](http://bobueland.com/cocos2d/?p=259)

its working very well,
but I need some sprites that move on my app to be on top of a tableView, I have tried with the property z, for cocos 2d but doesnt seem to work to place the sprite on top of the table,

```
tablaMenuBloq = [[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, -10, 150, 210) style:UITableViewStylePlain]autorelease];
    tablaMenuBloq.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( ( 90 * M_PI ) / 180 );

    tablaMenuWrapper =[CCUIViewWrapper wrapperForUIView:tablaMenuBloq];
    [self addChild:tablaMenuWrapper];


    //first sprite
    TSprite *ez = [TSprite spriteWithFile:@"butonA.png"]; //lets create a TSprite, named EZ, and the file is Easy.png.
    [ez SetCanTrack:YES];//The sprite can be tracked.

    [self addChild: ez z:2 tag:easySprite]; //lets add a tag to the sprite, in order to identify it later
    ez.position = ccp(290,300);//position of the sprite
    [TSprite track:ez];//and lets add this sprite to the tracked array.
```

Please note the sprite code created after the table also,

So how can I address this?

thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That z index exists in the context of Cocos2D's view only, and cannot affect the view's relationship with the subviews that you are adding on top of it.

See [Cocos2d node over uikit element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987519/cocos2d-node-over-uikit-element).